# Lesscss in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, less, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to use lesscss in Visual Studio without getting errors and use IntelliSense to coding better?

*p.m.* I'm using [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dd5635b0-3c70-484f-abcb-cbdcabaa9923) but I still getting errors.

**update1**

I tried [this](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) but VS still show me errors with this:

```
#t1 {
    .shadow;
    .transition;
    .radius;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Essentials 2012 is another. And it is really good.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

I think it was created by the same guy who developed BlogEngine.Net

Answer (score 1):

I came across this site just by googling but i don't have any experience using it.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench